# Android Studio e SDK

Tags: android, android-studio

Todas às vezes que instalo o android Studio ele vem sem o SDK.Já verifiquei os caminhos mais comuns onde o instalador o coloca e nada. O que posso fazer neste caso , como instalo o SDK do android ?

Comment: Geralmente no windows, é instalado em `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`. A pasta `AppData` é oculta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geralmente, o Android Studio já vem com o SDK intalado. Mas você pode instalar o SDK através da aba SDK Manager, localizada na parte superior do Android Studio.